# Font size smaller in <input> than in <body>

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, I have specified a font size of 0.97em for the body tag. The input tag also has a font size set at 0.97em.

Why does the font inside input appears slightly smaller than font inside the body? This is true for all browsers...

Please see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vXBLt/

```
 <body>

Note the font size difference: <input type="text" id="text" name="text" value="Note the   font size difference:" class="form_css" />
 </body>


 body {
 margin : 0;
 padding : 0;
 line-height : 1.45em;
 font-size : 0.97em;
 color : #000000;
 font-family : Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 }

.form_css {
width : 300px;
height : 25px;
padding-left : 5px;
padding-right : 5px;
line-height : 1.45em;
font-size : 0.97em;
color : #000000;
font-family : Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
border : #000000 solid 1px;
border-radius : 0;
margin : 0;
vertical-align : middle;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: that's because `input`' do not appreciate odd numbers. Make it `0.96em` and see it fly!

Comment: I get exactly the same font-sizes in latest Chrome, [here's a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HbdiS.png) from my browser, zoomed in and with the text duplicated and moved a bit too for better comparison.

Comment: @Jeroen I thought so at first, too, but note how the n's align perfectly, while the colons do not.

Comment: Nope, it's an exact match. My screenshot was borked, I apparently didn't select the entire colon. If I [redo the experiment properly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bBTfy.png) the colons are also the same.

Comment: By the way, in Firefox latest I *do* see the behavior mentioned, [unless I use the jsfiddle CSS reset](http://jsfiddle.net/vXBLt/2/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because em-based sizes are inherited downwards. On body, you use 0.97em, which is a fraction of the "standard"-size of 16px. On input you do it again - so its 0.97*0.97*16px.

Set the input size to

```
font-size: 1em;
```

Or nothing. And it will be fine.

In firefox, you can see this by using the inspect tool and then checking the "calculated" tab. 15.5167px is the actual size.

Comment: It has nothing to do with *inheritance*. It depends on the meaning of the `em` unit.

Comment: True. What would be a better word? Cascades?

Comment: It’s just the meaning of `em`, comparable to the meaning of `%`. Actually the problem would be basically the same if `97%` size were set on nested elements.

Answer (score 1):

Form elements are not the same as just plain HTML. Mainly because you can edit them, therefore simplifications are implemented.

One of them is `odd v. even`.

Odd numbers are more difficult to scale than even numbers (that's just how computers work). So instead of going `0.97` put `0.96` or `0.98`. 0.01 Which is such a minor difference, I dare anyone to spot it!